# PHP require_once relative to variable document root

Tags: php

I'm trying to include using require_once, however, I don't always know what the file structure will be relative to the DOCUMENT_ROOT...

it could be... 
/config.php  or /theapp/config.php  or  /dev/theapp/config.php  or /something_else/theapp/config.php

I *COULD* path back from the file like require_once('../config.php') except in some cases the files may be in a symlink directory.

Basically I'm trying to find a way where NO MATTER the circumstance, any files that call the config.php file can find it.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [`include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) configuration setting is for. I usually set it in the Apache config for my site, or in a local `.htaccess` file. Use the [`php_value`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) directive.

So, basically, in your Apache config file:

```
php_value include_path .:/var/www/where-your-site-is
```

Then, from your scripts, you just use:

```
<?php
  require_once 'conf/config.php';
  require_once 'views/template.php';
?>
```

No matter where in your sites directory structure you are.

Comment: You could also set this at runtime in a php file: $path = '/usr/lib/pear'; set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);

Answer (score 2):

If you have PHP 5.3+ use this:

```
// My page: /dir1/dir2/welcome.php
// My include: /inc/top.php 
require_once(__DIR__.'/../../top.php');
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php): `__DIR__` is the directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dirname(__FILE__)`
It returns the complete path of your script.

example

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/config.php');
```

Comment: I think the post formatter zapped your answer -- this should probably read __ FILE __ (with no space between the underscores and FILE)

Comment: So, right now I have a file (3 levels deep) calling via:
 require_once('../../../config.php'), how would I use dirname and scan back 3 levels?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a pretty simple solution that works when the app is running as one unit, as well as when the core system is linked in via symlink:

Instead of:

```
require_once('../../../config.php');
```

I use:

```
function changeDir($up_n){
    $split = explode("/",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
    array_pop($split); // Remove current file name
    for ($i=1; $i<=$up_n; $i++){ array_pop($split); }
    return implode("/",$split);
}

require_once(changeDir(3)."/config.php");
```

Just pop off